# HTTP/1.1" 404 1766, почему?

Tags: django

`[07/Oct/2020 00:48:44] "GET /static/main/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1766`
`[07/Oct/2020 00:48:44] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 644`
путь вроде-бы правильный, почему выдает ошибку, хз

возможно ошибка тут

```
    {% load static %}
    
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
              content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Fire Star</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="D:\Test\_XXXFireStarXXX_\_XXXFireStarXXX_\main\templates\main\favicon.ico" 
type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'main\main.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4>Fire Star Team</h4>
    </html>
```

Comment: В `settings.py` поди что-то не так, надо правильно все настроить. Отредактируйте вопрос, включите в него дополнительные подробности.

Comment: Пожалуйста, когда задаете такие вопросы, приводите фрагменты кода, которые связаны с ошибкой. Мне бы хотелось увидеть ваши настройки статики и шаблон, который вызывает этот css-файл

Comment: Уже отредактировал вопрос и добавил код